# Pickle сохраняет вместо файла непонятные символы. Python

Tags: python, pickle

Целый код представляет собой телеграм бота. Пытаюсь сохранить этот файл, и выдает такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот основной элемент кода, который неправильно работает:

```
users["@servoo"] = 580051506

with open("/Users/sarversalahutdinov/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my-app/Бот/users.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(users, f)
```

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Добро пожаловать! Я бот, созданный для написания пожеланий по улучшения нашей школы. \n\nНапиши /help для вызова администрации")
    if message.from_user.id not in users:
        users[f"@{message.from_user.username}"] = message.from_user.id
        with open("/Users/sarversalahutdinov/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my-app/Бот/users.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(users, f)
```

В файл сохраняются странные символы, но в консоль все выводится как надо [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd:
Понял, что надо было использовать "w вместо "wb и соответственные способы записи в файл

```
users = {}

with open("/Users/sarversalahutdinov/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my-app/Бот/users.pickle", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(str(users))
```

```
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Добро пожаловать! Я бот, созданный для написания пожеланий по улучшения нашей школы. \n\nНапиши /help для вызова администрации")
    if message.from_user.id not in users:
        users[message.from_user.username] = message.from_user.id        
        with open("/Users/sarversalahutdinov/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my-app/Бот/users.pickle", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            users = f.read()
            users = eval(users)
            print(users)
```

Но теперь проблема в том, что переменная "users" используется раньше, чем я ее задал, хотя я ее объявил практически в самом начале кода

Comment: Здесь всё нормально, именно такой формат и использует pickle

Comment: pickle - это бинарный формат, он не предназначен для просмотра человеком, только для обмена данными между программами на python. Не нужно использовать w вместо wb, нужно не указывать кодировку.